# Ist eine Referenz auf den »Götz von Berlichingen« automatisch vulgär?

Tags: colloquial, insult, euphemism

Das Schlüsselwort im Fragetitel ist *automatisch.*

Ich habe mal eine 10-minütige Sendung auf Arte gesehen, die empfehlenswerte [Karambolage](http://www.arte.tv/fr/104016.html), 
in der es im Wesentlichen um die kulturellen, politischen u. a. Unterschiede zwischen Frankreich und Deutschland geht. In einer Folge, die leider nicht mehr verfügbar ist, wurde haargenau erklärt, was *merde!* und ein paar französische Beleidigungen geschichtlich sind und, auf der deutschen Seite, was *Scheiße!* und *Leck mich am Arsch* kulturell bedeuten. Es gebe, so die Sendung, einen Euphemismus für den letzten Ausdruck, der mit dem Goethischen Helden **Götz von Berlichingen** zu tun haben soll. Das genaue Zitat, wie überall festzustellen ist, lautet:

> Sag deinem Hauptmann: Vor Ihro Kaiserliche Majestät hab ich, wie immer, schuldigen Respekt. Er aber, sag’s ihm, er kann mich im Arsche lecken!

Im Grunde genommen (und wenn mich mein Gedächtnis nicht täuscht) lautet der Euphemismus beispielsweise:

> Da könnte ich nur *Götz von Berlichingen* zitieren.

**Frage**: Ruft dieser Euphemismus automatisch ins Gedächtnis der Muttersprachler, *was* von Berlichingen sagte? Oder braucht man einen viel zu großen Kontext, um verständlich zu sein? Und wie aggressiv wäre das?

Comment: Ich hab den Ausdruck zwar schonmal gehört (glaube im Fernsehen - "Der kann mich mal Götz von Berlichingen"), wusste aber nicht, dass das für LmaA steht.

Comment: "evozieren" musste ich erstmal googlen :D

Comment: Was würde man normalerweise für *evoke* dann auf Deutsch sagen? *Hervorrufen*?

Comment: Ja, wortwörtlich sogar: *e (ex)* = aus, heraus; *vocere (vocare)* = rufen.

Comment: Die Frage sollte so formuliert sein, dass die Vulgarität der Erwähnung eines Zitats nicht von der Kenntnis *aller* Deutschsprachigen davon abhängt.

Comment: @c.p. Die deutsche Sprache kennt zwar viele Wörter aus dem Lateinischen, dies sind aber meistens Fachwörter (Medizin, Biologie, Rechtswesen, ...), bildungssprachlich oder sonst in irgendeiner Weise äußerst formell. In der Alltagssprache sind vielleicht etwa 15% der Wörter aus dem Lateinischen. Also, dass ist nur eine ganz grobe Orientierung. Die Zahl ist jetzt frei erfunden. Schlussfolgernd könnte man nun sagen, dass du ein jedes Wort, das aus dem Lateinischen kommt, hinterfragen solltest. Das ist natürlich übertrieben, aber es liegt nahe, dass Deutsche die Wörter nicht kennen.

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6tz_von_Berlichingen - Er war ein Ritter und auch ein Figur in einem Schauspiel von Goethe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich hab leider keine Belege dafür, aber ich bin mir sicher, dass der Zusammenhang zwischen dem Götz und *Leck mich am Arsch* (LmaA) nur einer Minderheit bekannt ist. Ich vermute, dass ihn nicht mal jeder Abiturient kennt. Deshalb wird

> Da könnte ich nur Götz von Berlichingen zitieren.

nur gebraucht, wenn der Redner / Schreiber ein bestimmtes Bildungsniveau voraussetzen kann – oder auch, um ein wenig eitel seine eigene Bildung zu demonstrieren. Ich hab das bislang nur selten gelesen und noch nie gehört, d. h., ich würde es auch eher der Schriftsprache zuordnen.

Ungleich populärere Phrasen, um LmaA zu evozieren, aber die Vulgarität zu mindern, sind:

> Leck mich!
>   Du kannst mich mal. *oder auch* Du kannst mich mal kreuzweise.

Wohlgemerkt: mindern. Sie sind noch so nah dran an der vollständigen Phrase, dass sie je nach Kontext durchaus als vulgär oder beleidigend empfunden werden können. Die zweite halte ich dabei noch für etwas zurückhaltender als die erste. Nochmal ein Stück milder ist:

> Du kannst mich mal gerne haben.

Das ist soweit verändert, dass zumindest für mein Empfinden die Vulgarität komplett verschwunden ist. Aggressiv ist das aber immer noch, wenn auch vielleicht nicht ganz so stark.

Gehört habe ich auch schon:

> Leck mich am Arm!

Hier wird das Wort des Anstoßes vermieden, aber durch Gleichklang doch wieder »evoziert«. Das dürfte bei den meisten Muttersprachlern funktionieren. Ansonsten gilt das zuvor Gesagte: Viele werden das trotzdem als vulgär und aggressiv empfinden.

Comment: Boah! Und *du kannst mich mal* bedeutet eindeutig LmaA!? (Und ich denke, der Beleg wäre gar nicht nötig. Es reicht, dass du Leute kennst, die das Zitat nicht kennen. Eine detaillierte Studie mit Statistik und so gibt's bestimmt nicht :D)

Comment: @c.p. Nun ja, da *du kannst mich mal* den "interessanten" Teil weglässt, bedeutet es erst mal nur eindeutig das, was der Gesprächspartner darunter versteht ;-) Aber ich wüsste nicht, was es sonst sein soll.

Comment: @c.p. Bei nochmal Nachdenken: nun ja, es gäbe da [noch ein paar Varianten](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=Du+kannst+mich+mal+&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou), aber letztlich laufen sie alle aufs selbe hinaus. Vor allem glaube ich nicht, daß jemand, der ausdrücklich "nur" `Du kannst mich mal gern haben` sagen will, dies zu "Du kannst mich mal" verkürzt.

Comment: Ich glaube dass der Euphemismus *Götz-Zitat* weithin bekannt ist. Das hat mit Bildungsniveau nicht unbedingt etwas zu tun, man muss Goethe nicht unbedingt im Original gelesen haben um den Ausdruck zu kennen.

Comment: @Ingmar Man muss ihn nicht gelesen haben, man muss noch nicht mal wissen, dass der *Götz* von Goethe ist - aber man muss schon mal was davon gehört haben, dass es einen Text "Götz von Berlichingen" gibt, in dem die Redewendung vorkommt. Und schon was das angeht, bin ich pessimistisch. (Vielleicht hätte ich heute morgen nicht die neueste Folge der Schülerantworten auf SPON lesen sollen...)

Comment: @Ingmar Ich kenn's definitiv nicht und hab die Frage auch nicht wirklich kapiert, eben weil ich es nicht kenne. Und ich denke sehr wohl, dass Bildungsniveau hier von Bedeutung ist. Ich hab mich im Deutsch-Unterricht für Goethe und Co. nen Pieps interessiert und das Gymnasium zu Gunsten einer Berufsschule abgebrochen. Die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass ich in meinem Leben mal was von Götz whatever gehört habe, liegt bei knapp 1%, und falls ja, dass ich es unmittelbar wieder vergessen habe bei 99%. Vielleicht liegts aber auch nur an meiner Ignoranz gegenüber dem Thema. Nun gut... Jetzt kenn ich es :)